# Wrong proof: The outer measure of [0,1]= 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The definition of outer measure of a set $E$ in $\mathbf{R}$ is: $m_*(E)=inf\Sigma|I_j|$ where ${I_j}$ the family of open intervals that cover $E$. I am wondering why this proof is wrong: 
$\forall \epsilon >0$.
Pick all the rational points $e_1,e_2,\cdots$ and To each rational point $e_i$ there exists a corresponding open interval $O_i$ that contains $e_i$ with length $\frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$. Then it is clear that the family of all such intervals contain [0,1] and we have $m_*(E) \leq m_*(\cup O_i)\leq \epsilon$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we claim that the outer measure of [0,1] is 0.

Clearly the proof is wrong. However, I don't know why it leads to the wrong result. Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: --> "Then it is clear that the family of all such intervals contain [0,1]"<--

Comment: at least you have a correct proof that the rationals have measure zero :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the proof goes wrong when it is written that something is "clear":

"Then it is clear that the family of all such intervals contain $[0,1]$ ..."

Not only is this not clear, it's not true! (Try to prove it, you will see where the issue arises.)

Comment: Alright. Clearly your first sentence is true. ^>^